# How to make seperate .js file pie chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

i have a pie chart code,just coping that code to our web page is easy and the result will start showing.

but my question is that i want to save that code in .js file separately and want to link that file with my web page to show that code.

can any body suggest me what should i need to do?

here is the  code -

http://jsbin.com/zocewinoye/2/edit?html,output

I just want to save that code in separate file and link that to my HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your Javascript code to a new file and save it as (for example) "script.js"
2. Link that file from your HTML like this after you have included d3 library:

Voila!

Comment: If I want to enter data manually in that file, So how can i do this?

Comment: Simply pass parameters via the URL querystring: ?data=5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25. Then you can split that query to get those values. Take a look at http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2013/11/20/getting-beyond-hello-world-with-d3/

Comment: I visited your suggested website. I was the same what I needed. I copied the code and past it respectively as the author said. But its not working. so can you suggest me what changes needed to make in html file